# Inner join on two different fields of 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which has fields `X,Y,Z,BAGID.` 
The BAGID is in the form of (12345-400) where 12345 is the user's id and 400 is the BAG's id.

I have another table which has fields `A,B,C,USERID.`
The USERID is in the form of 12345 which is same as the first part of BAGID.

So is it possible to join these two tables on the common USERID and get the fields USERID,X,Y,A,B?

```
Table 1:

X  Y  Z  BAGID(userid+bagid)    
1  2  4  12345-400

Table 2 :

A  B  C  USERID    
3  5  7  12345
```

I want the output as:

```
X  Y  A  B  USERID    
1  2  3  5  12345
```

Is it possible to have a join these two tables?

```
select Table1.X, Table1.Y, Table2.A, Table2.B, Table2.USERID
from Table1
inner join Table2
on Table1.BAGID = Table2.USERID;
```

I know i cannot user BAGID and USERID as they are different. But is it possible for me to use the userid part of the BAGID of Table1 which is the same as USERID of Table2?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract `USERID` out of `BAGID`:

```
select Table1.X, Table1.Y, Table2.A, Table2.B, Table2.USERID 
from Table1 
inner join Table2 on SUBSTRING_INDEX(Table1.BAGID, '-', 1) = Table2.USERID
```

This will work provided that there is only one `'-'` in `BAGID`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1cf38/1)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just join on LEFT(BAGID,5). Depending on the USERID DataType you may need to CAST it as well.

If the USERID portion of BAGIT is variable length you first need to find the length using INSTR(BAGID, '-')

Answer (score 0):

You can inner join on substring of table1 column

```
Select Table1.X, Table1.Y, Table2.A, Table2.B, Table2.USERID
From Table1
Inner join Table2 
ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(Table1.BAGID,'-',1) = Table2.USERID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using t sql you can use the SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) function to get only the first 5 characters of the bag id, and then join on that value. Ie

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON SUBSTRING(TABLE1.bagid, 0, 5) = table2.userid
```

If not using t sql, whatever you're using should have a similar substring function